# Remove top space between images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, whitespace

I got this... (img) https://imageshack.com/i/exRHvxtfp

I need this... (img) https://imageshack.com/i/pdvA6JXIp

What is the best way to do it? Is it possible with CSS?, can I do it with jQuery? I need the easiest way to do it

This is my CSS...

```
 <style>
    container{
         background-color:gray; 
    }
    .container img{
        display:inline;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
 </style>
```

Please! i need help

Comment: That depends on your html markup and also vertical-align won't work with inline, set inline-block instead.

Comment: @C-linkNepal can you, please, be more specific?, also if i use inline-block, the images get aligned to the bottom not to de top

Comment: Because irregular image size... you need to manage your html... or you can use massionry, search it.

Comment: You'll need to update your markup for this, as your images are of different height but same width, arrange them in columns rather than in rows.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore okay, that sounds like a solution, but how can i do it? is there any css markup for it?

Comment: Can you share your html too, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even better

Comment: ok, if you want a css only solution, `column-count` will be the best approach. But it won't work in IE 9 or below. [Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) is a nice example. Otherwise you can add some jquery code to add some div columns and sort the images in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/qcevnd02/)**

html

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x50"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
   <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x200"/></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 1em/1.67 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 1260px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was all i wanted, im just concerned about IE, i think it doesn't work on IE right?

Answer (score 0):

For all images, set style as 'float:left;'

Use this CSS:

```
img {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and more convenient way is to use a script like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

You can also try COlumn Count. Like this:

```
.gallery{-webkit-column-count: 7; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 7; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 7;

    -webkit-column-gap: 4px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 4px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 4px;}
```

Explanation: you want 7 columns so you span your content through 7 columns (I've added a 4px gap just in case you need it). It will work just as you want but.... you'll leave IE9 and older out of the picture

So, again, my recommendation is Masonry